# Which one is best apache nifi or Camunda for pipeline tasks

Tags: apache-nifi, pipeline, camunda

When I'm checking Apache nifi and Camunda both are suitable for pipeline tasks. I'm confused. Which one is best for pipeline tasks.

Comment: If I'm wrong please correct me. In Nifi also for data flow we are going to create task process. so I hope both we can use pipeline tasks.

Comment: Camunda is user tasks/workflow automation. Nifi is data flow without user interaction. And it's not clear what do you mean by "pipeline tasks" because first that popups in my mind is CI/CD tools like Jenkins.

Comment: inputs defined by users so for me camunda is good

Answer (score 3):

I used and developed both of them.

First of all, need to analyze the tools;

- Camunda is a bpm(Business Process Management) tool. It proceeds with workflow and managing decisions.
- Nifi is a data flow manager. It consumes the data from the "x" platform and proceed and then publish or send another platform or tool. You can solve all "cross-cutting" data problems with it.

Your question;
if "Pipeline task" means CI/CD operation, you don't need to use these tools. But if "Pipeline task" means that pushing the data and managing the process, your solution is changing by your plan.

- Processing the data without any user confirmation and consuming automatically depending on some decision that checks by tool, you can use **Apache Nifi**.
- Processing the data and need some confirmation by the user to resume the task (Also use some logic with the script to confirmation),  you can use **Camunda**.